# Creating a class the have a "list creation" method and an "append to the list" method?

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to create a class that can handle a string-to-list conversion and also is capable of adding to the created list. However I am not sure how to do that. If I provide the class with an already prepared list and have an "append" function, everything works fine:

```
class EnvObj(object):

    def __init__(self, envVariable):
        self.envVariable = envVariable

    def appendElement(self, newElement):
        self.envVariable.append(newElement)

    def listElements(self):
        return self.envVariable

initList=['APPLE', 'CAR', 'HOUSE', 'PEN', 'CAT']
myEnvObj = EnvObj(initList)

print "Initial List:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
print "Adding a new element"
myEnvObj.appendElement('BANANA')
print "A new listElements() request:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
print "Adding a new element"
myEnvObj.appendElement('MILK')
print "A new listElements() request:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
```

So this works, after each appendElement() stage, I can see the list growing just fine. However, when I try to create a method for creating the list and then handle the append, everything starts to fall apart.

```
envVariableList = []
class EnvObj(object):

    def __init__(self, envVariable):
        self.envVariable = envVariable

    def elementList(self):
        envVariableList = self.envVariable.split(":")
        return envVariableList

    def appendElement(self, newElement):
        envVariableList.append(newElement)

    def listElements(self):
        return self.elementList()

tmpString="APPLE:CAR:HOUSE:PEN:CAT"
myEnvObj = EnvObj(tmpString)
myEnvObj.elementList()

print "Initial List:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
print "Adding a new element"
myEnvObj.appendElement('BANANA')
print "A new listElements() request:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
print "Adding a new element"
myEnvObj.appendElement('MILK')
print "A new listElements() request:"
print myEnvObj.listElements()
```

In that second case, I cannot see the list actually being appended to. Apologies for the messy code, but I hope that I was able to illustrate the idea. I am sure that it has to with the fact that something is getting reset or lost every time the instance is created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `self` in your methods :

`def elementList(self):
    self.envVariableList = self.envVariable.split(":")
    return envVariableList`

`def appendElement(self, newElement):
    self.envVariableList.append(newElement)`

What you did is just making a new variable and return it when you call `myEnvObj.elementList()`. It didn't instantiate it in the object[1](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). By using `self.myvar = [...]` it solve your issue

Comment: You also should split in `__init__`

Comment: I was supposing that there are some other treatments, but else you're right.